# JpaRepository one to many list query not working properly

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

Thank You advance

I am getting all list mapped by details list as I queried only for some list.

when I query by status is A then it shows all details list which userdetail entity status is not A. I also tried with a native query but it did not work for me.

my tables:

```
@Table(name = "user_master_workflow")
public class UserMasterWorkflowEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id",unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private long name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userMasterWorkflowEntity",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<UserDetailWorkflowEntity> userDetailWorkflowEntityList;
}


@Table(name = "user_detail_workflow")
public class UserDetailWorkflowEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id",unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_master_workflow_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private UserMasterWorkflowEntity userMasterWorkflowEntity;

    @Column(name = "branch_code")
    private String branchCode;
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private long orderId;
    @Column(name = "status")
    private char status;
}
```

MY JPA Query

```
@Query("from UserMasterWorkflowEntity umwf " +
            "inner join UserDetailWorkflowEntity udwf on udwf.userMasterWorkflowEntity=umwf " +
            "where udwf.branchCode=:branchCode and " +
            "udwf.status='A'")
    List<UserMasterWorkflowEntity> getAllNotificationByNotificationHolderId(@Param("branchCode") String branchCode);
```

But I am getting All List mapped by master_id.

Comment: Try to explain for which query it's not  working what output you are getting and what is expected in post ..

Comment: @Eklavya

I only want a list of which status A form user_detail_workflow table JPA query mapping by the user_master_workflow table. I already have shown my query.

Table Detail Below
user_master_workflow Table 
  
    id name   
    1 abc  
    
user_detail_workflow Table    

    id user..._id branch_code order_id status
    1 1                    111     1           C
    2  1                    111      2           A
    3  1                    111    3           I